# How I can get reference to UIViewController from any of it's subview(UIButton, UITextField etc)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I want the reference of UIViewController when I have the reference to a button that is added to this UIViewController.

the situation is like a added a button to UIViewController from a different class method and now to preform action on that button I want reference to UIViewController

button is added in following way

```
 UIViewController *controller = (id)viewController;
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 17, 17);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(back:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
```

here is the code for button action

```
- (void)back:(id)button 
{
    UIButton *btn = (id)button;
    //[btn.UIViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I tried this but it's not working

```
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    UIViewController *vc = window.rootViewController;
    [vc.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: firstly you cant add a button in a UIViewController, it gotta be a UIView. 
'"- (void)back:(id)button" better be in the UIViewController. so that you can do    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: I don't want to use delegate

Comment: If you have a reference to the Button's action you can fire the touchUpInside event programmatically  `[button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]`

Comment: @GoodSp33d can I send controller to method with what you suggested ? please so me how I can do that ?

Comment: Every time when you need to send some information from child view to parent controller you should use delegate. This makes this view reusable and you avoid tight coupling between controller and view. The other solution is to have weak reference to parent controller or to iterate through parent view controllers. Both solutions are crappy compared with delegate pattern.